# A question about strongly continuous.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

I am reading a book about C*-algebra. In the book,

**Let $\phi$ be a linear functional on $B(H)$ ($H$ denotes a Hilbert space), if $\phi$ is strongly continuous, therefore, there exist vectors $\xi_{1}, \xi_{2},...,\xi_{n}$ in $H$ and $\delta>0$ such that $|\phi(a)|\leq1$, whenever $max_{k}\{||a(\xi_{k})||\}\leq\delta$ for all $a\in B(H)$**.

I can not understand this conclusion, could someone explain to me?

Comment: For continuous functions, the preimage of an open set is open. Isn't that all that's being used here?

Comment: Could you explain more specific? I am a begginer of C*-algebra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sets of the form $V(a_0,\xi_1,\xi_2,\dotsc,\xi_n,\delta) = \{ a\in B(H) \colon \|(a-a_0)(\xi_i)\| < \delta \text{ for } i=1,2,\dotsc,n \}$ for $\delta>0$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $\xi_i\in H$, $a_0\in B(H)$ forms a basis in the strong operator topology. Let $U$ be the open unit disk in $\mathbb{C}$. Since $\phi$ is continuous from strong-operator topology of $B(H)$ to $\mathbb{C}$ and $\phi(0)=0$, $\phi^{-1}(U)$ is open and so there exists $\xi_i\in H$ and $\delta>0$ so that $\phi(V(\xi_1,\xi_2,\dotsc,\xi_n,\delta)) \subseteq U$.

Comment: Thanks, minimalrho. But i suppose $V$ may be a base of neghborhoods of some point $x_{0}$.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I'm only considering neighborhoods of $0\in B(H)$. This is okay in this case since $\phi(0)=0$, but I should correct myself.

Comment: And I still have a confusion, in my question $\phi(a) \leq 1$ is a closed set. Does it make any difference from your answer? (In your answer: $U$ is an open unit disk.)

Comment: Since $U\subseteq\bar{U}$, the result you want still holds with no $a$ having $|\phi(a)|=1$. The reason why it's probably written that way is that the author wants to switch to a closed condition later on.

Comment: Do you mean $\phi(\overline{V(\xi_{1},\xi_{2},...,\xi_{n},\delta)})\subseteq \overline{U}$?